# How are jar files and .class files added to Java class path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

I have created a java project in eclipse to learn Core spring and I have added all the spring related jars to the lib folder I have created inside my project to build path. I am not sure how all the .class files and these jar files are added to the class path

Comment: `javac -cp ...`?

Comment: I want to know how jar files and .class files are getting added to classpath when I create a java project in eclipse

Comment: Well, eclipse, at its core, calls the compiler via CLI. So at the end of the day, eclipse uses `javac -cp ...`.

Comment: That might not be true (it probably isn't, considering that Eclipse has its own Java compiler). Are you asking about the compile-time classpath, or the runtime classpath?

Comment: What do you mean by _how_? Is a JAR or `.class` file missing or do you want to know, how it works? If the latter, please give an example to explain what you mean.